# Replace switch/case by #ifdef or something similar

Tags: c, switch-statement, conditional-compilation

I'm trying to replace the `switch/case` structure by an other tool doing the same thing but with better performance ( less execution time ... ), I have in mind the `#ifdef` method but I have no idea how to use it in such situation:

```
float k_function(float *x,float *y,struct svm_model model)
{
    int i;
    float sum=0.0;
    switch(model.model_kernel_type)  
    {
    case LINEAR :
        return result1;
    case POLY :
        return result2;
    case RBF :
        return result3;
    case SIGMOID :
        return result4;
    default :
        return 0;
    }
}
```

PS :

```
typedef   enum   kernel_type   {LINEAR, POLY, RBF, SIGMOID};
```

Comment: Before you are trying nanoptimizations, you better understand the difference between the compiler and the preprocessor and function of each.

Comment: You won't be able to use preprocessor conditionals unless `model.model_kernel_type` is a constant defined at compile time. It doesn't look like it is.

Comment: are you sure you need better performance ? and if so, are you sure that a change in this bit of code will give you the performance gain you need ? ie. did you measure this ?

Comment: Have you actually profiled the performance of your code and determined that this `switch` statement is actually a performance problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I already commented, I do not believe preprocessor statements are what you are looking for. To use a preprocessor conditional, `model.model_kernel_type` would need to be a constant defined using a `#define` statement.

I do not know the internals of the switch statement, as it could be O(n) or O(1) depending on how the compiler handles it. If you needed to be sure of a O(1) time complexity, you could simply replace your switch statement with a lookup table like so:

```
float model_type_results[4] = {result1, result2, result3, result4};

...

return model_type_results[model.model_kernel_type];
```

Comment: Thanks. I've been bouncing between C and python a lot lately.

Comment: and a decent optimiser would probably generate very similar code to this, anyway.

Comment: I'd note that this is not likely to be faster than the original `switch` statement.  Barring some really good optimizations, the small lookup array has to be initialized for every call to the function. You can avoid that by making it `static`, but that means an extra memory lookup and dereference.  This is definitely one option the OP should actually benchmark, but I suspect the original `switch` statement is going to be hard to beat performance-wise.  Especially if the original actually only has four cases in it.

Comment: @GemTaylor From my experience, no, not necessarily. This is requiring space, and the optimizers usually don't decide on tradeoffs unless explicitly instructed.

Comment: The jump table and code to jump through it can be smaller than the equivalent chain of conditional statements if all possible values in a range are covered. Whether the compiler can deduce that the jumps can be further optimised to calls, I don't know, but I'd have thought that was an easy tradeoff, albeit very specific.

Comment: @gem: The compiler can jump through a jump table; it doesn't need to call through the jump table.

Comment: Yes, you are right -  this is returning values, not making function calls. But the same principles apply.

Answer (score 1):

I imagine the problem is not just 1 case statement, but code that is littered with similar case statements.

The c++ virtual function table is a similar concept for avoiding these sorts of case statements proliferating through the code. It is not actually difficult to implement function table semantics in C structures.

Traditionally, they have been written as just member function pointers, but the use of a single per-class function table pointer is more space efficient if there are many objects of each class.

Answer (score 0):

`#ifdef` is a compile-time operation, not a run-time operation.  It's not the solution you are looking for here.

Honestly, if your `switch` only contains four cases, there's not a lot you can do to improve on it.  If you're seeing any kind of slowdown here, it's in how your results are being computed (which you don't show).